# How do I clean up this jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have this function that I would like to condense into some iterator. How could this function be cleaned up?

All need to act sequentially, as in: When one function returns, the next one begins. All odd children should fade out after fading in, and all even children should fade in and not fade out after.

Please note that this code is in CoffeeScript, so no semicolons.

I'm also having a problem with after the 8th child (e.g. if I continue on to '.title-sword:nth-child(9), etc) the function stops working. My thinking is there is a limit for embedded functions in depth but I am not able to verify this.

```
$('.title-sword:nth-child(2)').css('visibility', 'visible').hide().fadeIn('fast').fadeOut('fast', ->
    $('.title-sword:nth-child(3)').css('visibility', 'visible').hide().fadeIn('fast', ->
        $('.title-sword:nth-child(4)').css('visibility', 'visible').hide().fadeIn('fast').fadeOut('fast', ->
            $('.title-sword:nth-child(5)').css('visibility', 'visible').hide().fadeIn('fast', ->
                $('.title-sword:nth-child(6)').css('visibility', 'visible').hide().fadeIn('fast').fadeOut('fast', ->
                    $('.title-sword:nth-child(7)').css('visibility', 'visible').hide().fadeIn('fast', ->
                        $('.title-sword:nth-child(8)').css('visibility', 'visible').hide().fadeIn('fast').fadeOut('fast')
                    )
                )
            ) 
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: You can easily make a (kind of) recursive function, passing the selection and a running index. Might depend on your actual markup though. I would avoid using `.title-sword:nth-child(X)` over and over again if you can just access the X-th selected element.

Comment: Is anything wrong with a regular for loop?

Comment: @Niko: A normal loop does not wait for the animation. I don't think it is possible at all.

Comment: You just need to go backwards and use the loop to construct the chain.

Comment: I'd be inclined to start with `var titleSwords = $('.title-sword')` and then access the individual ones with `titleSwords.eq(2)` and so forth (together with whatever looping/recursion solution seems best). I think it would make it easier to read, but also it should be more efficient since it only runs a selector against the DOM once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (no CoffeeScript, since I'm just a regular JS guy):

```
(function() {
    var i=2, elm,
        step = function() {
            elm = $('.title-sword:nth-child('+i+')');
            if( !elm) return;
            elm.css('visibility','visible').hide();
            if( i%2 == 0) elm.fadeIn('fast').fadeOut('fast',step);
            else elm.fadeIn('fast',step);
            i++;
        };
    step();
})();
```

This code will run the desired function starting with the second child, and repeating until there are no more children.

Comment: `!elm` needs to be `!elm.length`

Comment: @charlietfl Why? If `elm` is null, trying to get `elm.length` will cause an error.

Comment: `elm` won't ever be null since the `$()` function will - when passed a selector - always return a jQuery object (but possibly an "empty" one with `.length` of 0).

Comment: @Kolink nnnnn explanation covers it. Here's a fiddle to support it http://fiddle.jshell.net/Rdpn9/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('.title-sword:nth-child(n+2):not(:nth-child(n+9))').css('visibility', 'visible').hide().fadeIn('fast').fadeOut('fast')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RfHj2/1/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the elements are all siblings, this should work:

```
function doFades($el){
    $el.css('visibility', 'visible').hide().fadeIn('fast').fadeOut('fast', function(){
            var $next=$(this).next();
            if($next.length){
                doFades( $next);
            }
    }); 
}

doFades( $('.title-sword:nth-child(2)') );
```

I'm not familiar with coffeescript syntax but should be easy to modify

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to run the selector operation just once and then iterate through the results of that.  Here's a generic function that could be used for your purpose:

```
fadeInOutChildren(parentSelector, lowChild, highChild) {
    var items = $(parentSelector).children();
    var index = lowChild;

    function next() {
        if (index <= highChild) {
            items.eq(index++).css('visibility', 'visible').hide().fadeIn('fast').fadeOut('fast', next);
        }
    }
    next();
}

fadeInOutChildren(".title-sword", 1, 7);
```